# Issue with 'Current Location' on iOS Google Maps App

Tags: ios, google-maps, currentlocation

In my application, I am attempting to give a user directions from her 'Current Location' to an arbitrary destination. To do this I send them to the Google Maps App on the iPhone / iPod passing the correct directions string. However, it seems that when you pass 'Current Location' as the starting point, the Google Maps app has a decently high chance of setting the green pin to the wrong spot.

What causes this? Does the Google Maps App cache the current location, and use that for the green pin placement? If so, how do you ensure 'Current Location' will use a non-stale cache?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How far off is it?  Are you trying to generate walking directions or driving directions?  Driving directions may be trying to automatically drop you on a road to start.

Comment: It is much further off base than just finding the nearest street, sadly. It has been averaging several kilometers off base.